# Is there any method (function) in drupal which gets called after nodes being created.

Tags: 7, social-network

I am creating a custom module for Drupal 7. I wanted to post the node that gets created of type "Article" to facebook wall so that user doesn't have to manually create a wall post.

For that I need to get a method (function) in drupal which gets called as soon as the nodes gets created, where I can put my Facebook API codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`hook_node_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)

This is from API page:

> Respond to creation of a new node.
>
> This hook is invoked from node_save() after the database query that
>   will insert the node into the node table is scheduled for execution,
>   after the type-specific hook_insert() is invoked, and after
>   field_attach_insert() is called.

```
function MyModule_node_insert($node) {

  if($node->type == 'article') {
    //your code here
    custom_func();
  }
}

function custom_func() {
  //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this goal is http://twitterfeed.com. It allows you to export RSS (generated by views) to several social networks, including Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases

```
 hook_node_insert();
```

does the job. The hook_node_insert() is called before actual database write query so you cannot retrieve nid from that node. Another hook called *after* saving node is:

```
hook_node_postinsert();
```

Available after installing module

https://drupal.org/project/hook_post_action